# Using points of elevation stored as Google Fusion Table to draw elevation profile

Tags: elevation

I recently extracted a huge number of elevation data from government plans and has inputted to Google Fusion Table. Now I wish to obtain a elevation profile from these data along a route, e.g. a bus route. Is there any method, e.g. using GIS software, to accomplish the above mission?

Please see my sample of elevation data collected in the format of Google Fusion Table here. If it is advised to convert the data into other format I will do so.
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1tBcHh6y1Ri62zAbZnFo9jr0NQlLZkLK6VuD5Btd5

BTW I am just a newbie to GIS.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of free tools which will allow you to create an elevation profile.  There's a **[useful website](http://www.geocontext.org/publ/2010/04/profiler/en/)** which will allow you to import KML, KMZ or GPX files and it will create an elevation profile.

Another method is to create a KML file of your route and open it in Google Earth. If you right click on your route in Google Earth, and select Elevation Profile, the profile appears below.

[image]

[image]

If you want to accomplish this in a proper GIS program, you can do so if you have the 3D Analyst extension in ArcGIS.  Here's **[the page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/fundamentals-of-creating-profile-graphs.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_BEA96884E78E4DEB8F31465584DFBD7D)** on Fundamentals of creating profile graphs.

Similarly, you can also do this in QGIS using the [**Profile tool**](https://github.com/etiennesky/profiletool).

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a elevation database on my own. So how do I use my own elevation data to conveniently produce an elevation profile?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS.

Comment: So I think you can just use the profile tool I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Hi I have just edit the question, see if you can further answer my question.